# HTML Modals Intertwined on click action, should be separate

Tags: html, django

I have two modals on a single HTML template. When I implemented the second modal, the first one became tied to its actions and I want them to be separate. When I click the button to add time, I want the just the time form modal to show. When I click a user, I want some of their profile details shown on the right of the page. As of now, when I click the 'add time' button, they now stack together.

Here is a picture of the issue:

[image]

You can see that the front modal covers the form behind, I want these to be separate actions. When I click a button to add time, just this modal form should show:
[image]

When I click on a user button, just this modal should show on the right hand page:
[image]

Here are my button HTML:

```
                                                        <button class="btn btn-danger add-btn mb-0" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#timetrackModal"><i class="ri-add-line align-bottom me-1"></i> Add Time Entry</button>
                                                        <button type="button" class="btn py-0 fs-16 text-body" id="settingDropdown" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">
                                                            <i class="ri-stack-line"></i>
                                                        </button>

                                                                <a href="#userProfileCanvasExample{{tech.pk}}" class="avatar-group-item" data-bs-toggle="offcanvas" data-bs-trigger="hover"
                                                    data-bs-target="#userProfileCanvasExample{{tech.pk}}" aria-controls="userProfileCanvasExample{{tech.pk}}" title={{tech.username}}>
                                                                    <div class="rounded-circle avatar-xs">
                                                                        <div class="avatar-title rounded-circle bg-info">
                                                                            {{tech.username|first}}
                                                                        </div>
                                                                    </div>
                                                                </a>
```

Here is the Modal HTML:

```
    <div class="modal fade zoomIn" id="timetrackModal" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered modal-lg">
            <div class="modal-content border-0">
                <div class="modal-header p-3 bg-soft-info">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel"> Add Ticket Labor</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close" id="close-modal"></button>
                </div>
                <form action="{% url 'apps:tickets.time_entry' tickets.pk%}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {% csrf_token %}
                    {{ form.media }}
                    {{ form.as_p }}
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <div class="row g-3">
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div id="modal-id">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-12">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="tasksTitle-field" class="form-label">Add Time Entry for Ticket</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="ticket" class="form-control" placeholder="Title" value="{{tickets.pk|add:1000}} | {{tickets.name}}" readonly />
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="choices-text-input" class="form-label">Hours</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" data-choices data-choices-search-false
                                    id="choices-lead-input" name="hours" id="hours" value="0" >
                                        <option value="0">0h</option>
                                        {% for i in "x"|rjust:"10" %}
                                            <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{forloop.counter}} h</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="choices-text-input" class="form-label">Minutes</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" data-choices data-choices-search-false
                                    id="choices-lead-input" name="minutes" id="minutes" value="0" >
                                        <option value="0">0m</option>
                                        {% for i in "x"|rjust:"59" %}
                                            <option value="{{forloop.counter}}">{{forloop.counter}} m</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-4">
                                <div>
                                    <label for="choices-text-input" class="form-label">Technician</label>
                                    <select class="form-select" data-choices data-choices-search-false
                                    id="choices-lead-input" name="created_by" id="created_by"  >
                                        {% for tech in technicians %}
                                        <option value="{{tech.technician_id}}" >{{tech.username}}</option>
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <label for="date-field" class="form-label">Working Date</label>
                                <input type="text" name="created_at" class="form-control"
                                    data-provider="flatpickr" data-date-format="Y-m-d" value="{{ today|date:"Y-m-d" }}"
                                    placeholder="Choose Work Date" required />
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-lg-8">
                                <label for="date-field" class="form-label">Log Comment </label>
                                <textarea class="form-control bg-light border-light" id="bodyTextarea1" rows="3" placeholder="Enter comment" name="comment"></textarea>
                            </div>

                    <div class="modal-footer">
                        <div class="hstack gap-2 justify-content-end">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="add-btn">Add Time</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    {% for tech in tickets.assignment.all %}
    <div class="offcanvas offcanvas-end border-0" tabindex="-1" id="userProfileCanvasExample{{tech.pk}}">
        <!--end offcanvas-header-->
        <div class="offcanvas-body profile-offcanvas p-0">
            <div class="team-cover">
                <img src="{% static 'images/small/img-9.jpg'%}" alt="" class="img-fluid" />
            </div>
            <div class="p-1 pb-4 pt-0">
                <div class="team-settings">
                    <div class="row g-0">
                        <div class="col">
                            <div class="btn nav-btn">
                                <button type="button" class="btn-close btn-close-white" data-bs-dismiss="offcanvas" aria-label="Close"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-auto">
                            <div class="user-chat-nav d-flex">
                                <div class="dropdown">
                                    <a class="btn nav-btn" href="javascript:void(0);" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                        <i class="ri-more-2-fill"></i>
                                    </a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="ri-inbox-archive-line align-bottom text-muted me-2"></i>Archive</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="ri-mic-off-line align-bottom text-muted me-2"></i>Muted</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="ri-delete-bin-5-line align-bottom text-muted me-2"></i>Delete</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div><!--end col-->
            </div>
            <div class="p-3 text-center">
                {% if tech.picture %}
                <img src="{% static 'images/users/avatar-2.jpg'%}" alt="" class="avatar-lg img-thumbnail rounded-circle mx-auto profile-img">
                {% else %}
                <div class="avatar-lg img-thumbnail rounded-circle mx-auto profile-img">
                    {{tech.username|make_list|first}}
                </div>
                {% endif %}
                <div class="mt-3">
                    <h5 class="fs-16 mb-1"><a href="javascript:void(0);" class="link-primary username">{{tech.username}}</a></h5>
                    <p class="text-muted"><i class="ri-checkbox-blank-circle-fill me-1 align-bottom text-success"></i>Online</p>
                </div>

                <div class="d-flex gap-2 justify-content-center">
                    <button type="button" class="btn avatar-xs p-0" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Message">
                        <span class="avatar-title rounded bg-light text-body">
                            <i class="ri-question-answer-line"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn avatar-xs p-0" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Favourite">
                        <span class="avatar-title rounded bg-light text-body">
                            <i class="ri-star-line"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>

                    <button type="button" class="btn avatar-xs p-0" data-bs-toggle="tooltip" data-bs-placement="top" title="Phone">
                        <span class="avatar-title rounded bg-light text-body">
                            <i class="ri-phone-line"></i>
                        </span>
                    </button>

                    <div class="dropdown">
                        <button class="btn avatar-xs p-0" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="avatar-title bg-light text-body rounded">
                                <i class="ri-more-fill"></i>
                            </span>
                        </button>

                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="ri-inbox-archive-line align-bottom text-muted me-2"></i>Archive</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="ri-mic-off-line align-bottom text-muted me-2"></i>Muted</a></li>
                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0);"><i class="ri-delete-bin-5-line align-bottom text-muted me-2"></i>Delete</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="border-top border-top-dashed p-3">
                <h5 class="fs-15 mb-3">Personal Details</h5>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <p class="text-muted text-uppercase fw-medium fs-12 mb-1">Number</p>
                    <h6>{{tech.mobile}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <p class="text-muted text-uppercase fw-medium fs-12 mb-1">Email</p>
                    <h6>{{tech.email}}</h6>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p class="text-muted text-uppercase fw-medium fs-12 mb-1">Location</p>
                    <h6 class="mb-0">{{tech.city}}, {{tech.state}}</h6>
                </div>
            </div>
            
            <div class="border-top border-top-dashed p-3">    
                <h5 class="fs-15 mb-3">Attached Files</h5>
                
                <div class="vstack gap-2">
                    <div class="border rounded border-dashed p-2">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 me-3">
                                <div class="avatar-xs">
                                    <div class="avatar-title bg-light text-secondary rounded fs-20">
                                        <i class="ri-folder-zip-line"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
                                <h5 class="fs-13 mb-1"><a href="#" class="text-body text-truncate d-block">App pages.zip</a></h5>
                                <div class="text-muted">2.2MB</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 ms-2">
                                <div class="d-flex gap-1">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18"><i class="ri-download-2-line"></i></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18 dropdown" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="ri-more-fill"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-share-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Share</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-bookmark-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Bookmark</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-delete-bin-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="border rounded border-dashed p-2">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 me-3">
                                <div class="avatar-xs">
                                    <div class="avatar-title bg-light text-secondary rounded fs-20">
                                        <i class="ri-file-ppt-2-line"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
                                <h5 class="fs-13 mb-1"><a href="#" class="text-body text-truncate d-block">Project Rocket admin.ppt</a></h5>
                                <div class="text-muted">2.4MB</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 ms-2">
                                <div class="d-flex gap-1">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18"><i class="ri-download-2-line"></i></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18 dropdown" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="ri-more-fill"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-share-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Share</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-bookmark-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Bookmark</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-delete-bin-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="border rounded border-dashed p-2">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 me-3">
                                <div class="avatar-xs">
                                    <div class="avatar-title bg-light text-secondary rounded fs-20">
                                        <i class="ri-folder-zip-line"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
                                <h5 class="fs-13 mb-1"><a href="#" class="text-body text-truncate d-block">Images.zip</a></h5>
                                <div class="text-muted">1.2MB</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 ms-2">
                                <div class="d-flex gap-1">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18"><i class="ri-download-2-line"></i></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18 dropdown" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="ri-more-fill"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-share-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Share</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-bookmark-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Bookmark</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-delete-bin-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="border rounded border-dashed p-2">
                        <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 me-3">
                                <div class="avatar-xs">
                                    <div class="avatar-title bg-light text-secondary rounded fs-20">
                                        <i class="ri-image-2-line"></i>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-grow-1 overflow-hidden">
                                <h5 class="fs-13 mb-1"><a href="#" class="text-body text-truncate d-block">bg-pattern.png</a></h5>
                                <div class="text-muted">1.1MB</div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="flex-shrink-0 ms-2">
                                <div class="d-flex gap-1">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18"><i class="ri-download-2-line"></i></button>
                                    <div class="dropdown">
                                        <button class="btn btn-icon text-muted btn-sm fs-18 dropdown" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                            <i class="ri-more-fill"></i>
                                        </button>
                                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-share-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Share</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-bookmark-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Bookmark</a></li>
                                            <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#"><i class="ri-delete-bin-line align-bottom me-2 text-muted"></i> Delete</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="text-center mt-2">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Load more <i class="ri-arrow-right-fill align-bottom ms-1"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!--end offcanvas-body-->
    </div><!--end offcanvas-->
    {% endfor %}
```

This started happening when I added the timetrackModal. When I remove it, the UserProfileCanvas modal works fine. I have tried working with the classes, the id tags, and getting stumped. The work independently, but when both constructed it leads to a layered modal

Note: The HTML returns data using Django as a web framework